# AttributeError: module 'django.conf.global_settings' has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'

Tags: python, django, юнит-тесты, settings, django-urls

AttributeError: module 'django.conf.global_settings' has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF' - ошибка при написании юнит-теста, сам тест такой:

```
from unittest import TestCase
from django.test import Client
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure(DEBUG=True)


class TestViews(TestCase):

    def test_main_page_GET(self):
        client = Client()
        response = client.get('registration/')

        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
        # self.assertTemplateNotUsed(response, 'quiz_core_app/main_page.html')
```

В файле settings.py эта переменная для корневых urls указана верно, DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE тоже указан, при попытка изменения этого теста ошибка уходит, но появляются другие и при решении их эта ошибка опять дает о себе знать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.conf import settings

settings.configure( 
    ROOT_URLCONF=__name__,
)
```